# Relation between refactoring and reverse engeneering

Tags: refactoring

refactoring must happen before reverse engeneering or theres no relation between them?
My teacher asked us about it, and the possible answers are:

a) There's no relation between them 
b) refactoring needs to happen before reverse engeneering

c) refactoring benefits reverse engeneering

for me, B and C are right but i'm still having this doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A)

Refactoring is modifying code while keeping the behavior the same.

Reverse engineering either looks at decoded assembly, and recreates a program or, it looks at the look/behaviour and recreates it.

Comment: but applying refactoring doesnt make your code easier to have a reverse engeneering?

Comment: if you reverse engineer something, you don't have code to start with

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of refactoring is to make code cleaner and more maintainable, without changing its behavior. It has nothing to do with reverse engineering.